# Kotlin Flow with catch operator still completes

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am having trouble understanding how the `catch` operator works in a kotlin `Flow`.
[Here is the catch documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/catch.html)

Questions:

1. Why doesn't the presence of a `catch` allow the `Flow` to continue upon encountering an exception, rather than complete?
2. Placement of the `catch` operator seems to change the behavior.  Why can't I place the `catch` operator at the end of the chain to see the same result?  In my example, it only executes if I place it BEFORE `onEach`.

[Example gist](https://gist.github.com/gregisdumb/95709d4531fbe01983c38ace08f5a865)

First example, placing the `catch` BEFORE `onEach`:

```
fun main() {
    // Flow of lambdas that return a String (or throw an Exception)
    flowOf<() -> String>({ "Hello " }, { error("error") }, { "World" })
        // Map to the result of the invocation of the lambda
        .map { it() }
        // This line will emit the error String, but then the flow completes anyway.
        // I would expect the flow to continue onto "World"
        .catch { emit("[Exception caught] ") }
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .launchIn(GlobalScope)
}
```

**Actual result:**
`Hello [Exception caught]`

**Expected result:**
`Hello [Exception caught] World`

Second example, placing the `catch` AFTER `onEach`:

```
fun main() {
    // Flow of lambdas that return a String (or throw an Exception)
    flowOf<() -> String>({ "Hello " }, { error("error") }, { "World" })
        // Map to the result of the invocation of the lambda
        .map { it() }
        .onEach { println(it) }
        // I would expect this catch to emit, but it never gets here.
        .catch { emit("[Exception caught] ") }
        .launchIn(GlobalScope)
}
```

**Actual result:**
`Hello`

**Expected result:**
`Hello [Exception caught] World`

Or, since the `onEach` happens before the `catch`'s emission, the `catch`'s emission would be ignored?  In which case, the expected output would be this?:
`Hello World`

Comment: Alex.T answered this properly, but I thought it'd be good to note here that for the second code snippet, the catch does actually reach there, but all you do it emit the "[Exception caught] " String, but never print it.
If you do add another `.onEach { println(it) }` after that line and before the `launchIn` you'll see that it does print both things, "Hello" and "[Exception caught] ".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easiest way for me to explain what you are doing there is to simplify it into syncronous code. You are basically doing this:

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf("Hello", "error", "World")
    
    try {
        for (s in list) {
            if (s == "error") error("this is the error message here")
            println(s)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("the exception message is: ${e.localizedMessage}")
    }
}
```

output:

```
Hello
the exception message is: this is the error message here
```

As you can see, the exception is caught, but it can't prevent the stop of the `for` loop. The same way in which that exception stops the `map` function.

Flow.catch will catch an exception and stop it from propagating (unless you throw it again), but it can't go a step back (to the map fun) and tell it to magically start again from where the next element would have been or etc.

If you want that, you need to put a normal `try/catch` inside the `.map` fun. So it would be:

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf("Hello", "error", "World")


    for (s in list) {
        try {
            if (s == "error") error("this is the error message here")
            println(s)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("the exception message is: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
the exception message is: this is the error message here
World
```

The way `Flow.catch` is usually used is to catch an exception that would prevent the next step, like if you have:

```
//pseudo

flow
    .map{/*code*/}
    .filterNotNull()
    .doSomethingRisky() //this can throw an exception
    .catch {} //do something about it
    .doSomethingElse()
```

In this scenario, even if `doSomethingRisky` throws an exception, the flow will still get to the `doSomethingElse`. This is more or less the use of the `Flow.catch`.

Comment: yes, and no. If you would have, let's say, 2 other calls to `.map`, if you didn't have that `.catch` it would never reach the subsequent 2 calls. With the `.catch` it will reach them (but only with the elements that can be processed before the first exception). But to process all the elements, you need to also put a normal try/catch inside the `.map` function as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Alex. T Looking at the catch documentation, they provide an example: 
`
    flow { emitData() }
        .map { computeOne(it) }
       .catch { ... } // catches exceptions in emitData and computeOne     
       .map { computeTwo(it) }     
       .collect { process(it) } // throws exceptions from process and computeTwo  
`
So, my map { it() } would be that risky call that should get caught, right?

Comment: Sorry for all the terrible formatting by the way.  First time on SO.. having issues here :-)

Comment: comments can't be formatted sadly, but the ` char does help a bit to highlight things. Btw, your question is well formatted and I'd consider it high quality, with proper examples and quite clean in what you want to achieve. I've seen worse from people that have 2 years old accounts. (Btw, there is a big chance that this comment, and your latest one will be deleted, since they are off-topic, just so you know)

Comment: Take a look for this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/71806318/10479081

Answer (score 3):

While AlexT response is fully correct, there is a trick to keep the flow alive. You can wrap your actual flow into another flow. The inner/actual flow will complete but the outer flow will stay active. This is handy if your flow fails but you want to offer a "retry" button in the UI:

```
private val sourceFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)
private val innerFlow = flow { ... } // Whatever your flow is!
val outerFlow = sourceFlow.flatMapLatest {
   innerFlow.catch {
      // Handling, e.g. emitting an error state to the UI (can show retry button)
      emit(ViewState.Error("Some error")
   }.onStart {
      println("Inner start")
   }.onCompletion {
      println("Inner end")
   }
}.onStart {
   println("Outer start")
}.onCompletion {
   println("Outer end")
}
```

If you want to retry the entire flow, just do `sourceFlow.update { it + 1 }`. This will update the `0` in the `MutableStateFlow` causing the `flatMapLatest` to be called again and then your `innerFlow` is kicked off again. You can do the same with a `MutableSharedFlow` instead of the `MutableStateFlow<Int>`, but I found this a bit more tricky to do as you need to emit from a coroutine in this case.

With this setup you need to subscribe to `outerFlow` which will emit all values of `innerFlow`

Comment: Looking at my old response, I realise that I didn't actually give a direct solution, I just explained why OP's code doesn't work as they think it should/. This answer is an actual solution to the issue.